# Different Popups When Flagging

Tags: support, flags

When I flag posts, I usually get the following popup:

[image: popup when flagging posts]

I have a lower declined rate for comment flags. Thus, when flagging comments, I usually get the following popup:

[image: popup when flagging comments]

As far as I understand, after being temporarily banned from flagging, a red pop-up is used for a while. But I don't really want to reproduce this.

Are there any explicit thresholds for these popups? Does this affect the priority for raised flags to be reviewed?

Comment: No clue if there's thresholds, but no, there's no such thing as a priority flag or a priority flagger. Mod flags go straight into a queue for mods, but that's the closest thing you get, and that still isn't affected by the flagger. Or rather, while mod flags go straight to mods, some flags still aren't prioritized because of the flagger

Comment: What did you flag that comment as?

Comment: @Zoe, i see. It just seems that if some reports are taken seriously, the rest are taken less seriously by default.

Comment: Not really. I think there was a recent change to popups though - IIRC, it's historically been "Thanks, we'll look at it". Not sure when or how it changed (because SE doesn't exactly keepachangelog(.com)), but all flags are treated equally within their respective queues, regardless of whether said queue is public or restricted to moderators.

Comment: @Zoe I'm pretty sure the comment flag wording was changed after the "SO is toxic" Twitter debacle.

Comment: @rene, this pop-up notification appears definitely for NLN-flags. It may have also appeared for other flags, but I cannot say for sure.

Comment: @rene which one? There were several :')

Comment: @Zoe 2019 obviously: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/323623